# TabBar More Button "remembers" last opened page

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hi stackoverflow community,

I really need help with a problem, I found no working solution.

I have an App which uses the TabBar for navigation.

There are 8 Tabs, 4 on the main screen and 4 in the tableview of the "MORE" Button.

My Problem is that when I go to one of the pages in the "More" menu, and then change to another page by clicking on a Tab, the open page will be saved.
And when I now click again on the "More" Button, this page will be directly opened.

But I want the "More" Button to ALWAYS open the List with the possible selections.

How can I achieve this?

I'm really thankful for any help :)

PS: I implemented the TabBar via the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. What you could do is to overwrite the –tabBar:didSelectItem: item method and manage to pop the visible view controller off the "more" item navigation stack back to its root view controller every time the more item was selected.

Be aware that this may cause confusion and frustration on the user's side, depending on the depth of  the navigation stack (i.e. the deeper the user goes, the higher the frustration might be).

Also, this might be against Apple Human Interface Guidelines and therefore there is a chance that this custom behavior leads to a rejection.